# how to change the color of select text

Tags: html, css

how to change the color of the dropdown text that I am given red but initially it look like black when we click that it look like red, so how to change that initially it look like red color

```html
<select>
  <option style="color:red">one</option>
  <option style="color:red">two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply the style to the select, not to the option.

Setting `style="color:red"` will set the color of the option to red.

Setting `style="color:green"` will set the color of select to green

```html
<select style="color:green">
  <option style="color:red">one</option>
  <option style="color:red">two</option>
</select>
```

If you dont want the color of options to be updated, use `color: initial` for the option.

```css
select {
  color: red;
}

select option {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is, you want the drop-down texts in red before clicking it.

```
<Select style="color:red">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
</select>
```